# parsing multiple files in javaCC

Tags: javacc

I want to parse multiple files. I have JavaCC code which generates the parser.
It works fine when I parse the first file (a.txt). But, I want to parse multiple files. because the first file (a.txt) call many files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you you use the `STATIC=false` option.
Then you can do something along these lines

```
void Include() :
{    Token t ;
}
{
    <INCLUDE>  t=<STRING> 
    {
        try {
            File f = extractFile( t.image ) ;
            Parser p = new Parser( new FileReader(f) )
            p.Start() ; }
        catch( ParseException x ) { throw x ; }
        catch( TokenManagerError x ) { throw x ; }
        catch( Throwable x ) { throw new ParseException( x.getMessage() ) ; }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is solved .   in fact, I had a qoute in addition in my string. Thanks in advance.     However, i want parse  multiple files that is call by one file.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "However, i want parse multiple files that is call by one file." Well that's the question my answer is addressing.

Comment: Hello,  parse multiple files that is call by one file  work fine.  However, I want catch of exceptions in each parsed file. Thanks in advance

Comment: My example code above catches exceptions thrown while parsing included files.  It just throws them again, but it does catch them.  You might want to modify ParseException and TokenManagerError to include a file name as well as a line number.  This can be done.

Comment: Hello, Thanks very much for your help.  in fact, a have another question about the  name of file.  in may grammar i defined Token <ID> :

Comment: Hello, Thanks very much for your help.  in fact, I have another question about the  name of file.  in may grammar i defined Token <ID> : < iden >
    (
      < iden >
    | < DIGIT >  | < #iden : [ "A"-"Z", "a"-"z" ] >
| < #DIGIT : [ "0"-"9" ] >)  . HOWEVER, the name of file is composed of CONCATENATED lettres and (number.number.number.typeOfFile).  for exemple AAAA 1.2.3.txt . how I can define identifier of my files.

Comment: I'm trying to parse regular expressions using JavaCC but I encountered a problem with variable " Y "  composed 
of lettre and number for exemple : " JAVA 1.7.1" .

knowing that I have already defined the  Token 

<id > = < lettre > | <number>

< #lettre : [ "A"-"Z", "a"-"z"]>
| < #number : [ "0"-"9" ] >


in execussion , the parser processing the variable " Y "   as number.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a separate question. Please don't raise new questions in comments. Post them as new questions.  However if you read the FAQ you may find there answer is there and there is no need to ask in stack overflow at all.